# gyp ERR! : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1

Tags: node.js, npm, visual-studio-2017, loopbackjs, strongloop

I just start learning the loopback and how it woks but getting error while installing the strongloop
 `npm install -g strongloop`

```
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\strongloop\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64\\node_sqlite3.node" "--module_name=node_sqlite3" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\strongloop\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\strongloop\\node_modules\\sqlite3\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.28
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js build --fallback-to-build --module=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node --module_name=node_sqlite3 --module_path=C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64' (1)

> strong-agent@2.1.2 install C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-agent
> node-gyp rebuild || exit 0


C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-agent>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Warning: Missing input files:
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-agent\build\..\src\features.h
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
  strong-agent.cc
  win_delay_load_hook.cc
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-agent\src\compat.h(20): fatal error C108
3: Cannot open include file: 'v8-debug.h': No such file or directory (compiling source file ..\src\strong-agent.cc) [C:
\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-agent\build\strong-agent.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\strong-agent
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok

> ws@0.4.32 install C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\node-inspector\node_modules\ws
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(3557): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object::Ge
  t' (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(24): error C2039: 'IsNear
Death': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roa
ming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
  c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1548): note: see declaration of 'Na
  n::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(67): warning C4996: 'v8::
PersistentBase<v8::Object>::MarkIndependent': was declared deprecated (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc) [C:\
Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(566): note: see declaration of 'v8::PersistentB
  ase<v8::Object>::MarkIndependent' (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\nan\nan_object_wrap.h(124): error C2039: 'IsNea
rDeath': is not a member of 'Nan::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>' [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Ro
aming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
  c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\nan\nan.h(1548): note: see declaration of 'Na
  n::Persistent<v8::Object,v8::NonCopyablePersistentTraits<T>>'
          with
          [
              T=v8::Object
          ] (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(106): error C2
039: 'Handle': is not a member of 'v8' [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-v
alidate\build\validation.vcxproj]
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8-platform.h(16): note: see declaration of 'v8'
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(106): error C2
061: syntax error: identifier 'Handle' [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-v
alidate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(112): error C2
065: 'target': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-val
idate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(112): error C2
660: 'v8::FunctionTemplate::GetFunction': function does not take 0 arguments [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(6126): note: see declaration of 'v8::FunctionTe
  mplate::GetFunction' (compiling source file ..\src\validation.cc)
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(131): error C2
661: 'v8::Value::ToObject': no overloaded function takes 0 arguments [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\s
trongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(140): error C2
065: 'Handle': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-val
idate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(140): error C2
275: 'v8::Object': illegal use of this type as an expression [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloo
p\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
  c:\users\admin\appdata\local\node-gyp\cache\12.18.3\include\node\v8.h(3496): note: see declaration of 'v8::Object'
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(140): error C2
065: 'target': undeclared identifier [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-val
idate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(140): error C2
182: 'init': illegal use of type 'void' [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-
validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(141): error C2
448: 'init': function-style initializer appears to be a function definition [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
c:\users\admin\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\src\validation.cc(146): warning
C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'int' to 'node::addon_register_func' of greater size [C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roamin
g\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\validation.vcxproj]
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\strongloop\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

also I tried  `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` but facing same error
`npm cache clean --force`
`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools --vs2017`
`npm install -g node-gyp`
all these commands also not able to solve these issue
**need help to resolve these issue**
also I installed the c++ dependencies from Visual Studio Build Tools 2017
15.9.30 nothing works for me